# High level Win32 image file I/O?

Tags: c++, windows, image, winapi, io

I want to read in image files into memory in a Windows C++ application. What would be a reasonably simple solution, perhaps similar to what IOS provides in `UIImage`?

I would like to have a reasonable number of file formats to be supported.

I would need to have some low-level access provided to the bitmaps for image processing.

I have read quite a bit on the internet, and it looks like the Windows DIB could be a reasonable in-memory representation. Beyond that, I couldn't find sample code to read, say, a JPEG or a PNG into a DIB in memory.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: There's LoadImage, and the OLE Image...something...Path, and not the least GDI+. I think I would first check LoadImage, and if it only loads resources, I would use GDI+. The OLE image stuff is archaic technology, even if it works.

Comment: I would recommend looking at [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654(v=vs.85).aspx) the GDI interfaces are officially deprecated at this point. NOTE: GDI on vista and above is just a limited abstraction of WIC. Save yourself pain and just use WIC.

Comment: Do you want to display the images within the application, or just process them?

Answer (score 3):

I just checked and [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does indeed support loading from a file, via the flag `LR_LOADFROMFILE`.

So that would be my first choice.

Secondary choice, GDI+ (note that it requires quite a bit of fiddling with init stuff to get ordinary good quality, and at least some years ago it still had dependency on the `min` and `max` *macros* from `<windows.h>`). Third choice, the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentioned in a comment to the question. Fourth choice, [`OleLoadPicturePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and family.

---

**Addendum**: As noted in a comment `LoadImage` is limited to “bitmaps” for loading an image file. On my system the test program below reports OK loading for .bmp file, and fails for .gif, .png and .jpg.

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout
#include <string>           // std::wstring
using namespace std;

auto get_exe_path()
    -> wstring
{
    int const buffer_size = MAX_PATH;
    wstring result( buffer_size, L'#' );
    int const n_characters = GetModuleFileName( 0, &result[0], buffer_size );
    assert( 0 < n_characters && n_characters < buffer_size );
    result.resize( n_characters );
    return result;
}

auto get_exe_folder_path()
    -> wstring
{
    wstring const exe_path = get_exe_path();
    int const i = exe_path.rfind( L'\\' );
    return exe_path.substr( 0, i + 1 );
}

void test( wstring const& image_name )
{
    wstring const image_file_name = get_exe_folder_path() + image_name;
    wcout << image_file_name << endl;
    HANDLE const image = ::LoadImage(
        0,              // HINSTANCE hinst,
        image_file_name.c_str(),
        IMAGE_BITMAP,
        0, 0,   // int cxDesired, int cyDesired,
        LR_LOADFROMFILE
        );
    wcout << image << endl;
    DeleteObject( image );
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    test( L"test.bmp" );  wcout << endl;
    test( L"test.png" );  wcout << endl;
    test( L"test.gif" );  wcout << endl;
    test( L"test.jpg" );
}
```

---

**Addendum 2**: Just to check it out I also tested the Windows Imaging Component functionality, and it indeed handles all four image types above. Most of the size of the code below is due to reusable write-once support for COM (I just cooked it up from scratch yet again, so it's a bit sketchy, only what's needed here). Still, this code does not display the image or do anything else with it, and with WIC that's simlarly complex…

Although this code has partial g++-support I haven tested it with g++. As I recall g++ only supports the Windows API as it was as of Windows XP. And I'm not sure when WIC was introduced (even though it can be used with Windows XP).

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincodec.h>       // IWICImagingFactory

#include <algorithm>        // std::swap
#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <iostream>         // std::wcout
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string>           // std::string, std::wstring
#include <utility>          // std::move

#ifndef CPPX_NOEXCEPT
#   if defined( _MSC_VER )
#       define CPPX_NOEXCEPT   throw()
#   else
#       define  CPPX_NOEXCEPT   noexcept
#   endif
#endif

#ifndef CPPX_NORETURN
#   if defined( _MSC_VER )
#       define CPPX_NORETURN   __declspec( noreturn )
#       pragma warning( disable: 4646 )     // "has non-void return type"
#   elif defined( __GNUC__ )
#       define CPPX_NORETURN    __attribute__((noreturn))
#   else
#       define CPPX_NORETURN    [[noreturn]]
#   endif
#endif

namespace cppx {
    using std::string;
    using std::runtime_error;

    auto hopefully( bool const condition )
        CPPX_NOEXCEPT
        -> bool
    { return condition; }

    CPPX_NORETURN
    auto fail( string const& s )
        -> bool
    { throw runtime_error( s ); }
}  // namespace cppx

namespace process {
    using std::wstring;

    auto get_exe_path()
        -> wstring
    {
        int const buffer_size = MAX_PATH;
        wstring result( buffer_size, L'#' );
        int const n_characters = GetModuleFileName( 0, &result[0], buffer_size );
        assert( 0 < n_characters && n_characters < buffer_size );
        result.resize( n_characters );
        return result;
    }

    auto get_exe_folder_path()
        -> wstring
    {
        wstring const exe_path = get_exe_path();
        int const i = exe_path.rfind( L'\\' );
        return exe_path.substr( 0, i + 1 );
    }
}  // namespace process

namespace com {
    using cppx::fail;
    using std::move;

    enum Success { success };

    auto operator>>( HRESULT const hr, Success )
        -> bool
    { return SUCCEEDED( hr ); }

    struct Library
    {
        ~Library()
        { CoUninitialize(); }

        Library()
        { CoInitialize( nullptr ); }
    };

    template< class Interface >
    class Ptr
    {
    private:
        Interface*  p_;

    public:
        auto raw() -> Interface* { return p_; }
        auto operator->() -> Interface* { return p_; }

        void clear() { Ptr null; swap( *this, null ); }

        auto as_value_receiver()
            -> Interface**
        {
            clear();
            return &p_;
        }

        auto as_untyped_value_receiver()
            -> void**
        { return reinterpret_cast<void**>( as_value_receiver() ); }

        friend void swap( Ptr& a, Ptr& b )
            CPPX_NOEXCEPT
        { std::swap( a.p_, b.p_ ); }

        void operator=( Ptr other )
        { swap( *this, other ); }

        void operator=( Ptr&& other )
        {
            Ptr temp( move( other ) );
            swap( temp, *this );
        }

        ~Ptr()
        { if( p_ != nullptr ) { p_->Release(); } }

        explicit Ptr( Interface* p = nullptr )
            CPPX_NOEXCEPT
            : p_( p )
        {}

        Ptr( Ptr const& other )
            : p_( other.p_ )
        { if( p != nullptr ) { p_->AddRef(); } }

        Ptr( Ptr&& other )
            CPPX_NOEXCEPT
            : p_( other.p_ )
        { other.p_ = nullptr; }

        static
        auto create_local( CLSID const& class_id )
            -> Ptr<Interface>
        {
            Ptr<Interface>  result;
            ::CoCreateInstance(
                class_id, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                __uuidof( Interface ),
                result.as_untyped_value_receiver()
                )
                >> success
                || fail( "CoCreateInstance" );
            return move( result );
        }
    };

}  // namespace com

namespace app {
    using cppx::fail;
    using std::wstring;
    using std::wcout; using std::endl;

    void test( wstring const& image_name )
    {
        wstring const image_file_name =
            process::get_exe_folder_path() + image_name;
        wcout << image_file_name << endl;

        auto                            p_factory   =
            com::Ptr<IWICImagingFactory>::create_local( CLSID_WICImagingFactory );

        com::Ptr< IWICBitmapDecoder>    p_decoder;
        p_factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
            image_file_name.c_str(),
            nullptr,
            GENERIC_READ,
            WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, // Cache metadata when needed
            p_decoder.as_value_receiver()
            )
            >> com::success
            || fail( "IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromFilename" );

        com::Ptr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> p_frame;
        p_decoder->GetFrame( 0, p_frame.as_value_receiver() )
            >> com::success
            || fail( "IWICBitmapFrameDecode::GetFrame");

        UINT w, h;
        p_frame->GetSize( &w, &h )
            >> com::success
            || fail( "IWICBitmapFrameDecode::GetSize" );

        wcout << "(w, h) = (" << w << ", " << h << ")" << endl;
    }

    void cpp_main()
    {
        com::Library const  com_usage;

        test( L"test.bmp" );  wcout << endl;
        test( L"test.png" );  wcout << endl;
        test( L"test.gif" );  wcout << endl;
        test( L"test.jpg" );  wcout << endl;
        test( L"test.bogus" );
    }
}  // namespace app

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        app::cpp_main();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        wcout << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: `LoadImage` is simple to use, but it supports only icon, cursor, or bitmap files.

Comment: On the plus side, it *is* easy to use. It may well be a good starting point for the OP, since attempting to support more file types is a time consuming exercise. Using this, the OP can concentrate on other stuff first.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [GDI+ Bitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It supports BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF.

---

Edit:

### Example:

**Header**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
...
class App {
    ULONG_PTR gditoken;
    App::App() : gditoken(0) { }
...
```

**Source**

```
bool App::Init() {
    if(Status::Ok != GdiplusStartup(&gditoken, &GdiplusStartupInput(), NULL))
        return false;
    ...
    return true;
}

void App::Destroy() {
    if(gditoken) GdiplusShutdown(gditoken);
    ...
}

void App::DoStuffWithBitmap(WCHAR* filename) {
    Bitmap bm(filename);
    if(Status::Ok == bm.GetLastStatus()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `FromFile()` method can also be used

```
void App::DoStuffWithBitmap(WCHAR* filename) {
    Bitmap* bm = Bitmap::FromFile(filename);
    //Note: If the file is not found, FromFile returns an object anyway.
    if(bm && Status::Ok == bm->GetLastStatus()) {
        ...
    }
    delete bm;
}
```

To access the bits, you could maybe use (haven't tested)

```
int GetDIBits(
  HDC hdc,           // handle to DC
  HBITMAP hbmp,      // handle to bitmap
  UINT uStartScan,   // first scan line to set
  UINT cScanLines,   // number of scan lines to copy
  LPVOID lpvBits,    // array for bitmap bits
  LPBITMAPINFO lpbi, // bitmap data buffer
  UINT uUsage        // RGB or palette index
);
```

To get the HBITMAP, use

```
Status Bitmap::GetHBITMAP(
    const Color &colorBackground,
    HBITMAP *hbmReturn
);
```

on the bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gdiplus.h>

unsigned long gdiToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiStart;
gdiStart.SuppressBackgroundThread = FALSE;
gdiStart.GdiplusVersion = 1;
gdiStart.DebugEventCallback = NULL;
gdiStart.SuppressExternalCodecs = NULL;

if (GdiplusStartup(&gdiToken, &gdiStart, NULL) == Gdiplus::Ok)
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap *gdiBm = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile("myImage.xxx");
    //Do some stuff with your bitmap
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiToken);
}
```

This is an incomplete example for reading a bitmap using Gdi+, but should get you started.

It supports the most common image formats, such as JPEG, GIF, PNG, TIFF, BMP. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Please note that GDI is considered *LEGACY* and is just a limiting abstraction over WIC

Comment: @Mgetz: GDI+ is not GDI. What is WIC.

Comment: @Mgetz where does it say that **GDI+** is a legacy solution? I've recently gone through MSDN docs and nowhere could I read about it.

Comment: @W.B. it's listed along with GDI+ under legacy graphics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309470(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: anyway, as far as the marketing department at microsoft is concerned everything a year old is legacy. i would not base any decisions on marketing info.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Windows Imaging Component is the COM based replacement for the GDI/GDI+ Imaging API, it supports a LOT more formats and a lot more capabilities.

Comment: @Mgetz fair enough. But as long as it's not deprecated and it's _much_ easier to use than WIC, I'd go with that.

Comment: @Mgetz: why should one use a microsoft over-complicated solution for that. rather dumb.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do image processing on loaded images why not using openCV?

it can load the most common image formats into a system independent matrix format and provides a lot of image processing routines.